# Plots with set line color appear with slightly different color

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

**Problem**

I am plotting two different data sets in two different plots, and I want the graph in the same colour (blue). Obviously, I thought this is easily done by setting the colour of the markers and the lines, but although I use the same RGB code the plots appear with a different **blue**.

The illustrations below show the different appearance and this problem is the same if looked at in Matlab or exported as png, pdf, or jpeg. A colour print version also shows a different color. I know the colors are similar but if looked at properly they are not the same. And just to make sure, I do export them in the same size, same properties, same everything.

**Question**

Do I maybe have a simply plotting mistake ? Or is there a way to fix this ? I cant find a way to solve the problem.
Help is very appreciated!

**Plot1**
[image]

**Plot2**

[image]

Plot 3

[image]

**Code 1**

```
y=[0.3700    0.3600    0.350    0.3398    0.325    0.30]
h=plot(1:6,y,'Marker','o','Color',[ 0 0.4470 0.7410], 'MarkerFaceColor', [ 0 0.4470 0.7410], 'LineWidth', 1.5)
hold on
ax=gca;
ax.YLabel=ylabel('Test'); 
ax.XLabel = xlabel('Year');
l=legend('Whatever the legend says')
set([gca,ax.XLabel,ax.YLabel], 'FontName', 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8) 
set(l,'Fontsize',8,'Location', 'southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
set(gca,'LineWidth',1.0)
hold off**
```

**Code 2**

```
h=figure
hold on
yyaxis left
l1=plot(1:6,1:6);
l2=plot(1:6,2:7);
hYLabel=ylabel('Test'); 

yyaxis right
r1=plot(1:6,3:8);
hYLabel=ylabel('Test');
hXLabel = xlabel('Test');

a=sprintf('TestTest\n Test');
b=sprintf('Test Test\n Test');
c=sprintf('Test & Test\nTest Test');
hLegend=legend([l1,l2,r1,], a, b, c);
set([gca,hXLabel,hYLabel,hLegend] , 'FontName'   , 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8) 
set(hLegend,'Fontsize',8,'Location', 'southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
set(gca,'LineWidth',1.0)
ax=gca;


set(l1, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-','Color',[0 0.447 0.7410])
set(l2, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-.','Color',[0 0.447 0.7410])
set(r1, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-')
hold off
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You're asking why the two blue lines in Plot2 are slightly different?  Or do you want to make *all* lines in Plot2 blue?

Comment: The blue of plot 1 and the blue of plot 2 are different at least on my computer and in my print outs

Comment: Not sure what to tell you - the blue lines in Plot1 and Plot2 look the same on my machine.  Could it just be that a difference in line thickness is making them look like different shades of blue?  You're not asking about the axis coloring, are you?

Comment: No, not the axis, but the line thickness should be same if both are set to 1.5 shouldnt it ? At least they should be both 1.5!

Comment: No they won't because your figure sizes are different

Comment: @Suever thats what I said I export them with the exact same settings, and I dont change the size afterwards ( I just snipped it here, thats why they are of different size)

Comment: @KiW But look at the sizes of your fonts, they are smaller in the second one (yet they both have the same `FontSize`), so similarly the line width will be smaller in the second despite having the same `LineWidth`

Comment: @Suever, i edited the post with two figures exported with the same settings, on my screen and print out the colours are still slightly different.

Comment: The interesting thing is, if I leave out the Markers the lines show up with the same color ... and I have a friend here saying that it is not my eyes, but that the colors are different

Comment: @KiW They are the same color based on what you have posted: http://imgur.com/a/jWi0R

Comment: MATLAB uses anti-aliasing on lines so it's possible that it may *appear* to be slightly lighter but if you sample at the middle of the line they are exactly the same color

Comment: @Suever, interesting: I added a third illustration with white marker face color, that looks like the multiple line plot again - it really gets me confused. I think the first one looks a lot darker than the other two

Comment: @KiW Still the same color blue. it's best to check the color with a pixel color inspector tool rather than relying on your eye.

Comment: @Suever, can you recommend a tool ? I have never used one...

Comment: @Suever, last question - do they look the same for your eyes? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @KiW If you're using Chrome, something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorpick-eyedropper/ohcpnigalekghcmgcdcenkpelffpdolg) works well. And the first two may look slightly different to me but the third looks like the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of MATLAB use anti-aliasing when displaying and printing graphics (unless explicitly disabled), so it is possible that a thinner line of the same color may appear lighter than a thicker line of that same color.

You could optionally disable the anti-aliasing of a figure

```
set(gcf, 'GraphicsSmoothing', 'off')
```

Or globallly for *all* figures

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureGraphicsSmoothing', 'off')
```

All of the images you have posted above are the same shade of blue when you use a pixel color inspection tool rather than relying on your eye.